# PHP foreach style to input fields

Tags: php, function, validation

Evening,

Is it possible to add styles to the affected input field when using foreach in PHP? I am using this code to validate the input fields inside of my form:

```
$errors         = array();
$values         = array();
$error_message  = '';

if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $values[$key] = trim(stripslashes($value)); // input filter
    }

    if (check_input($values['invoice_email']) == false) {
        $errors['invoice_email'] = 'Please enter an email.';
    } else if (!preg_match('/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/', $values['invoice_email'])) {
        $errors['invoice_email'] = 'Invalid email format.';
    }

    if (sizeof($errors) == 0) {
        $values = array();
        print 'Form is OK!';
    } else {
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            print $error_message .= $error . '<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

And if anyone wants to see the function then the code is:

```
function check_input($input) {
    if (strlen($input) == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        // TODO: other checks?

        return true;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I forgot to say that I want the affected input field to have a border of 1px solid red to let user easily see what input field they're missing or having problems with.

Comment: Edited my question - look above :)

Comment: I'd say sure, why not? Have you tried it?

Comment: sure, but you'd need to check your `$errors` array while you're outputting the form. `if ($errors['name_of_field'] has an error message) { adjust CSS of form field }`

Comment: @MarcB Yes, sure. But I can't figure out how to adjust the CSS of the affected rows..

Comment: css is just styling rules. you need to figure out how you want your "error" fields to look different. either via a `style="..."` attribute, or assigning a specific class to the 'bad' fields, e.g. `class="error"`.

Comment: If I want it to be like `style="border: 1px solid red"`, do you then know how to add the border to those fields who turned out to be an error?

Comment: You could do something like `$errors['invoice_email'] = '<div class="error1">Please enter an email.</div>';` then just use the CSS for it in your `<style>` tags. Would be easier that way and to adjust it for any future use instead of an inline styling method.

Comment: @Fred-ii- `$errors['invoice_email'] = '<div class="error1">Please enter an email.</div>';` doesn't apply the border to the input field, but the error text instead

Comment: It was an example. You could set a class or ID to the input field(s) in question along with a ternary operator.

Comment: Oh, sorry then. :) do you have an example of your explanation? I really can't figure it out..

Comment: The CSS class would be `.error1 { border: 1px solid red; }` inside `<style>...</style>` tags is what I meant.

Comment: Yes, but where in the code should I apply that .error1 class?

Comment: I posted an example below @dinkode.dk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT #2

You could also make use of an [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) option, `required` without having to touch your functions.

- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/html5forms/

Example:

```
<input type="text" name="name" required />
```

Also, loading a stylesheet inside your loop with `<b></b>` tags wrapping your `$error` variable:

```
foreach ($errors as $error) {

echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="style_errors.css" type="text/css">';

    print $error_message .= '<b>' . $error . '</b>' . '<br />';
}
```

**CSS**

```
<head>
<style>
.error1x input {
border: 1px solid red;
}

input {
border: 1px solid green;
}

</style>
</head>
```

**Reference:**

- http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/css-forms.shtml

Other than this, you could use JS/jQuery and AJAX would also be an added option.

---

### EDIT #1

Here is another method, using a ternary operator:

```
<input type="text" name="input1" class="error1 <?php echo empty($_POST['input1']) ? $_POST['input1'] : 'noerror' ?>" />

<style>
.error1 { border: 1px solid red; }
.noerror { border: 2px solid green; }
</style>
```

and using the same CSS class for errors on inputs.

---

### Original answer

You could do something like

```
$errors['invoice_email'] = '<div class="error1">Please enter an email.</div>';
```

then just use the CSS for it.

Example:

```
<?php
...
if (check_input($values['invoice_email']) == false) {
        $errors['invoice_email'] = '<div class="error1">Please enter an email.</div>';
    }
    
...

?>

// inside the same file
<style>

.error1 { border: 1px solid red; }

.noerror {
background:#c0c0c0;
}

</style>
```

or loaded from an external stylesheet

Example input field

```
<input type="text" name="email" class="noerror">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not manipulate the DOM once it has been rendered with the use of PHP , you need Javascript to get that job done.

Nevertheless if you are creating the form with php and you are always reloading after each post.
Example:

```
echo "<form><input type='text' name='email' id='email'></input>.....</form>";
```

you can easily place whatever attributes you want inside your input to make it look like you want after the post has been made.

**Example:** 
After the page reload , print the input element with the attribute you want.

```
echo "<input type='text' style='border-radius:1px solid red' name='n1' id='n1'></input>";
```

If you are not creating the form with PHP and you want to change it without reloading the page , then the only way is to use javascript.

The equivelant in javascript would be:

```
document.getElementById['n1'].style.border="1px solid red";
```

Even though that alone can not help you. You need to make all the Validations with javascript in order to achieve that.